# Impact of search engine optimization with hosting plan

Tags: .net, windows, web-development, web-hosting, search-engines

I want to know is there a direct impact on the hosting plan. 
Why i am saying is, most linux hosting plan gives us modules for search engine optimization but not in windows plans. I have couple of site hosted with windows plan so how do I increase the search engine optimization for those without any external modules. 
I am planning to purchase dedicated IP for those too. 
Except from my code level optimizations (meta tags etc) is there anything else that I need to concentrate on hosting side or anything for ask my host provider for increase the search engine optimization specially for my windows plans.

Comment: [Is there any programming involved in this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: If only proper SEO was as simple as adding a module...

Comment: What module are you referring to? I'm aware of no SEO module for linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real effects webhosting has on SEO are:

1. downtime
2. page speed

Both of these really only come into play if you are on a shared webhost who places too many website on to one server. The side effect of this is the server is slow and occasionally experiences downtime. Google has publicly acknowledged using pageloading time as part of their ranking algorithm although they have indicated that only very slow loading pages are affected by this. Additionally, only pages with an extended downtime will be affected as well.

What you may be referring to is [Google's pagespeed Apache module](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/). It is designed to "optimize web pages by applying web performance best practices".

Answer (score 0):

One thing that JohnConde did not mention and I like to say is:

- shared  hosting

If you own an IP address which was for a spam site, then owning that site is kind of a risk.
because crawlers have marked them as spam in their database.

I have not heard about any SEO module, don't believe everything you here.

Comment: yes. its more good at least have a dedicated ip know rather a dedicated server because of expensiveness.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. If it's shared hosting then you don't own the the IP. It's **shared**. And a shared IP won't get you in trouble as most websites reside on shared IPs so it's a terrible way to ban or judge websites. It's easier just to ban by domain or by domain ownership.

Comment: You got me wrong @JohnConde. I can reference you to `The art of SEO` book to study about this issue more. when lots of spam sites reside in a specific IP address then bots decide to ban the whole IP address instead of banning one by one.

Comment: I don't think that book is any good. I consider it to be a waste of money.